# Dealing with NA in numeric vector and using transform

Tags: r, split, transform

I came up with a very hacky way of dealing with an issue I faced when combining two columns, but there must be a better/more efficient way to do what I did. Any suggestions for an R novice would be much appreciated.

I have two columns, one with code and the other with locations, for various years. The data is inconsistent over years, eg data in 2004 has codes and locations separated, while 2012 has codes and locations combined in the location column, leaving the code column empty. I first want to standardize the data over years, so one column, called code_location, has the code and location combined for all observation, then create two more columns, one with code and the other with location.

Here is the data:

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
observation     year     code     location
1               2004     23-940   town no. 1
2               2004     23-941   town no. 2
3               2012     NA       23-940 town no. 1
4               2012     NA       23-941 town no. 2"), header = TRUE)
```

I tried using `transform` and `paste` in the code below to combine the two columns, but it

```
df_combined <- transform(df, code_location = paste(code, location, sep = " "))
```

It worked in combining the code and location for 2004 observations, but it included the NAs from the code column in 2012 observations. (NB, both code and location are numeric vectors. I later use a regex where this becomes important. I tried `as.character` on code column to get rid of NA, but it then screwed up my regex later.)

```
observation     year     code_location
1               2004     23-940 town no. 1
2               2004     23-941 town no. 2
3               2012     NA 23-940 town no. 1
4               2012     NA 23-941 town no. 2
```

To get around this, I created a dummy that told me which observations had NA and which didn't, and then used `split` in order to create two dataframes, do what I need to get code_location, and then combined the dataframes again. Here is my code:

```
df$cheat <- ifelse(is.na(df$code) == T, 0, 1) 
ls_df <- split(df, df$cheat)
df_code <- ls_df[[2]]
df_na <- ls_df[[1]]

df_code <- transform(df_code, code_location = paste(code, location, sep = " "))

df_combined <- rbind(df_code, df_na)
```

And I get the following output, which is my desired output, but very roundabout.

```
observation     year     code_location
1               2004     23-940 town no. 1
2               2004     23-941 town no. 2
3               2012     23-940 town no. 1
4               2012     23-941 town no. 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ifelse` function:

```
transform(df, code_location = ifelse(is.na(code),
                                     as.character(location),
                                     paste(code, location)))
```

Note that `df$location` is a factor, so it needs to be converted to character if used by itself.

Answer (score 0):

the code in your example to read the data in does not work, please use `dput()` to provide usable example data.

I suggest a solution using `apply()` for your problem:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,function(row_tmp){
    if(is.na(row_tmp[3])){
        split_tmp <- strsplit(row_tmp[4]," ")[[1]]
        row_tmp[3] <- split_tmp[1]
        row_tmp[4] <- paste(split_tmp[-1], collapse = " ")
    }
    return(row_tmp)
})), stringsAsFactors= F)
```

The apply function goes through all the rows and splits the last column if an NA is encountered in the 3rd column.